# Removing duplicate chess games and then storing unique games in Postgresql

Tags: algorithm, postgresql, duplication

I have a very large number of chess games(around 5 million) stored in several pgn files(portable game notation).  If you aren't familiar with PGN, the result will basically be a csv file when parsed, with several fields containing info about the players, location, etc and then one larger text field with the moves separated by some delimeter, possible a space. There will be one row with such data per game.

The catch is there may be duplicate games.  Ultimately, I would like to store the unique set in Postgres, but what is the best way to get there?  I had two approaches in mind:

1.Insert a game at a time and then with each subsequent insert run a uniqueness test script that would only insert the game if it is unique.  Of course I would index fields as necessary to optimize this process(should I index all fields or just the 'cheap' ones like rating which are just integers)

2.Do a batch insert from the generated csv and only then check for duplicates.  The algorithm I was thinking of was to just loop through 1..(# games) ids, find the game with that unique id in Postrgres(if not already deleted) and then look forward for all game that are identical, delete all but one, and then move onto the next id/game.

The second method would insert much faster but would require searching n games each search.  The first one would insert more slowly, but would only search through n/2 games on average.  What are people's expectations about the efficiency of each approach?

Comment: `sort < infile | uniq > outfile` before you give it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: uniq only reports adjacent duplicates so that won't do the trick here

Comment: @Patrick: That's why you `sort` first.

Comment: Step one would be to get the games into canonical form: sanitize the strings, fix the date-formats, remove excessive whitespace and punctuation,(maybe) impose a fixed order on the attributes. Next, you can remove/suppress the trivial duplicates. Non-trivial duplicates (Typo's, misspelling of names) are much harder to detect.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do with the games data in the DB? If, for instance, you want to do all manner of analyses (given this opening, which is the most advantageous way forward? has the current board ever been played before?) then you need to store the game itself in a more intelligent way than as a string. Such decisions have a decisive impact on how you want to load your data.

Comment: I want to do lots of analysis, but that will only happen after I remove duplicates.  I will also have a table with positions(identified by the fen string of the position).  The position will belong to a particular game.  So no analysis will actually be performed using the string.  I will just store that for ease of converting the game back to pgn later.

Comment: Ultimately I want to be able to search and sort by position, player name, rating and date and generate statistics for each move from a given position