# Combining Duplicates in a Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, duplicates

My question closely relates to:
[Removing duplicate chess games and then storing unique games in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692850/removing-duplicate-chess-games-and-then-storing-unique-games-in-postgresql?rq=1)

I want to store a large set of chess PGN's avoiding duplicates like Kempchee.

Quoting Kempchee *"I have a very large number of chess games(around 5 million) stored in several pgn files(portable game notation). If you aren't familiar with PGN, the result will basically be a csv file when parsed, with several fields containing info about the players, location, etc and then one larger text field with the moves separated by some delimeter, possible a space. There will be one row with such data per game."*

Though for me in particular, I am using the follow tree structure as my data structure:

[image: My Tree]

The problem is that chess games can transpose into the same game through a different move order. I envisioned that if another tree branch transposed into a pre existing game in another node, that I would set the pointer to jump over to that node. The reason being is that I want a counter of how many times a certain game has been reached and have it branch from only a single node to save memory.

I can compare games using FEN which is best described here:
https://www.chessprogramming.org/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation

In short, it is unlike pgn as it just displays the current position of a chess game alongside some special details. So even if the pieces are all in the same place, one game could have castling privileges while another could not making it a different game.

So with a way to compare games and a large data set, how do I combine the duplicates in my tree without iterating through every possible node each insert?

**Extra Details:**

I am programming in Java

https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer : I would like to mimic what Lichess does in the bottom right where it states how many players played move X with the win/loss/draw ratio. I have been unsuccessful in finding guides that solely rely on ones own code.

Comment: You could keep the FEN strings in a hash table (map). Lookup there will be (close to) O(1). One caution, though: a game might merge into another game, and then diverge again.

Comment: Normally, castling and en-passant state are included in the board state and in the resulting Zobrist hash.

Comment: Yes wildplasser, in the FEN it gives those details as well. Jim, I thought about that too, but I came across the problem where I ran out of RAM going through all the games. I will probably just lower the amount of games I use.